# How to deserialize currencies list from openexchangerates.org to C# custom class or object?

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization, deserialization

I need to get currency values list in C# from here:
http://openexchangerates.org/currencies.json

which produces this kind of output:

```
{
    "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
    "ALL": "Albanian Lek",
    "AMD": "Armenian Dram",
    "ANG": "Netherlands Antillean Guilder",
    "AOA": "Angolan Kwanza"
        // and so on
}
```

I managed to get a string containing values above using C#, but I cannot find a way to deserialize that string into any custom class or anonymous object, so I am wondering how to do that?

Also, I am trying to use Json.NET to do that, but so far couldn't find a solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
```

--EDIT--

You can make it shorter

```
WebClient w = new WebClient();
string url = "http://openexchangerates.org/currencies.json";
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(w.DownloadString(url));
```

Comment: I found that a second ago myself, I posted my own answer without knowing that I got responses already)) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @LB - Wow! That is awesome! Much better than mine! Thank you so much!
I deleted my answer since it is redundant now.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using only .Net 4.0 and no third party libraries:

```
string url = "http://openexchangerates.org/currencies.json";

var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
string curStr = client.DownloadString(url);

var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var res = (js.DeserializeObject(curStr) as Dictionary<string, object>)
    .Select(x => new { CurKey = x.Key, Currency = x.Value.ToString() });
```

Outputs a list of anonymous objects with the keys and values from the list as properties.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks! Good to know the other way around this!
Our company will continue to use Json.Net though - the main reason is that it became so mainstream and stable, that it will be eventually included into the MVC 4:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%204%20RoadMap
(look at "What's Next?" section)